# The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine" For PHP webservice

Tags: php, service, protocols

I am calling a web service in my C# Code. The webservice is bulit in PHP. I am calling its
loadunload method. The webservice returns me the

```
"The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine"
```

error if I call the service with in 5 to 10 second delay. 
Here is the code I am using to call the service.

```
private MyServiceMachine client = new MyServiceMachine ();
client.loadunload();
Thanks in advance for help.
```

Here is the Excpetion I am getting
Exception Details:

```
Message:    The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine
Source: System.Web.Services
StackTrace:    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at SPLocker.Core.lendingMachineService.lendingMachine.loadUnLoad(String MID, String TS, String RE, Object BS)
   at SPLocker.Core.TransactionHelper.loadUnLoad(EnumLendingServiceMode mode, Int32[] BoxIDs, Boolean IsAllBOXes)
TargetSite: System.Net.WebResponse
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an error being returned by the C# HttpWebRequest class, rather than that by the endpoint server.

Turn on debugging is my reommendation.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sburke/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code)

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/ff098248-551c-4da9-8ba5-358a9f8ccc57

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility: when doing a POST, the server responds with a 100 continue in an incorrect way.

This solved the problem for me:

```
request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
```